# For My Raspberry PI Pico - VSCode build creates Ninja file but not the uf2 file

Tags: c, build

I am developing a simple test App for my RPI pico.
With some effort I now have a project that has no errors and seems to build except for one issue.
when it builds, it creates the "build.ninja" file, but it does not build a UF2 file to upload to the pico.

I have this set:

```
pico_add_extra_outputs(template)
```

in CMakeLists.txt.